# Is there a way to auto-populate anniversaries from Google Contacts to Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, google-contacts

There are lots of questions out there asking how to add birthdays and anniversaries to Google Calendar. I know how to auto-populate birthdays from Google Contacts to Google Calendar. And I know how to manually add anniversaries to Google Calendar as recurring events. My question is:

Is there a way to **auto-populate** anniversaries from Google Contacts to Google Calendar? Thanks.

Comment: There's an "anniversary" field on contacts. Mine populate my calendar. Don't yours?

Comment: Mine do not auto-populate. I add an Event, set the date, and then select "Anniversary" from the drop-down, but nothing appears on my calendar, neither on the actual date of the original event (the wedding) nor on the anniversary dates in subsequent years.

Comment: How long do you wait? It's not generally instantaneous.

Comment: @ale, to which calendar do your anniversaries populate?

Comment: Most of them were entered last year when I migrated from Outlook to the Google Suite. I just added one manually today.

Comment: I just realized they are populating to the Birthday calendar. @ale, if you want to say as much in an answer, I will accept it. * palm to forehead *

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah, that is a bit counter-intuitive. I'd forgotten that bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's imperfect, but if you put a date in the "Anniversary" field in Google Contacts, it will add annual events to Google Calendar on the "Birthdays" calendar with the text "John Doe's Anniversary". Of course, you'll need to display the Birthday calendar as well.

"Birthday" is a poor name for that calendar considering it's not just birthdays, but it's what we've got.

Comment: I just discovered that the name of the Birthdays calendar can be changed. Click the three dots > Settings > Name.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from ale here is correct, including the comment from Josh on the ability to rename the Birthday clendar to 'Contact Events' or something more adequate, as it can show anniversaries and other events from contacts.

However, if like me the 'Birthday' calendar simply does not appear in your Desktop/Laptop Google Calendar, under 'My Calendars' section, it is probably disabled on your mobile (which is crazy - Google should change that, but..). You'll need to go to Settings on you mobile Google Calendar and enable Birthdays. once you do that, it will appear on the laptop/desktop version of Google Calendar and you can rename it if you like. See [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/74565413/birthdays-suddenly-missing-from-calendar?hl=en) Google help question and Answer on this issue